# extracting a n element from a list with dolist on lisp

Tags: linux, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to create a function where it takes a list of letters as parameter and a single letter as a parameter. I want to remove the single letter from the list.

```
(defun extract-all (lett li)
   (let ((new-list nil))
     (dolist (letter li new-list)
        (if (eql lett letter)
             (setf new-list (cons nil new-list))
          (setf new-list (cons letter new-list))))))
```

so if I call the function with `(extract-all 'n '(i n t e l l))`, I want it to return `i t e l l` with the `n` removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** of all, you are not removing letters
([characters](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_ch.htm)), but rather
[symbols](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm):

```
(type-of 'n)
==> SYMBOL
```

**Second**, there is a standard function [`remove`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) to do just that:

```
(remove 'n '(i n t e l l))
==> (I T E L L)
```

**Third**, if you remove your "then" clause and [reverse](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_revers.htm) the result, you will get what you want:

```
(defun my-remove (object list)
  (let ((new-list nil))
    (dolist (element list (nreverse new-list))
      (unless (eql object element)
        (push element new-list)))))
(my-remove 'n '(i n t e l l))
==> (I T E L L)
```

**Note** that there are more ways to skin the cat, e.g.,

```
(defun my-remove (object list)
  (loop for element in list
    unless (eql object element)
    collect element))
```

However, it is always best to use the library.

See also [Where to learn how to practically use Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7224823/850781).

Comment: What is the purpose of unless?  is it some kind of else?

Comment: Which `unless`? [this](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_when_.htm) or [this](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_af.htm)?

Comment: So what is the question? why does CL have if, cond, when and unless? or what do they do? these are reasonable questions, please ask them separately!